# Create multiple XML files in Node Js

Tags: node.js, json, xml, loops

I am new to Node Js. I can't find a solution for this problem: I have to use a for loop to change the XML and to create a new one. It already gives me one new XML file but I want ten new XML files in the end. I hope my explanation wasn't too bad.

```js
for (t = 0; t < 10; t++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < homeTeamStarting11.length; i++) {
    homeTeamStarting11[i] = homeTeamStarting11[i];
    let roleHome = homeTeamStarting11[i].role['$t']; //string
    let roleAway = awayTeamStarting11[i].role['$t'];
    let currentPosition = homeTeamStarting11[i].position;
    let currentPositiontwo = awayTeamStarting11[i].position;
    if (roleHome === 'GOALKEEPER' || roleAway === 'GOALKEEPER') {

    } else if (roleHome === 'DEFENSE' || roleAway === 'DEFENSE') {
      currentPosition['y']['$t'] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 3;
      currentPositiontwo['y']['$t'] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 3;

      currentPosition['x']['$t'] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 3;
      currentPositiontwo['x']['$t'] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) + 3;
    } else {
      currentPosition['y']['$t'] = Math.random() * (90 - 1) + 1;
      currentPositiontwo['y']['$t'] = Math.random() * (90 - 1) + 1;
      currentPosition['x']['$t'] = Math.random() * (90 - 1) + 1;
      currentPositiontwo['x']['$t'] = Math.random() * (90 - 1) + 1;
    }

    homeTeamStarting11[i].position = currentPosition;
    //awayTeamStarting11[i].position = currentPositiontwo;

    //const TeamTogether = homeTeamStarting11.concat(awayTeamStarting11);


    json['lineup']['away']['startingEleven']['persons']['player'] = awayTeamStarting11;
    json['lineup']['home']['startingEleven']['persons']['player'] = homeTeamStarting11;


  }
  const Name = JSON.stringify(json);
  const xml = parser.toXml(Name);
  let xjz = getFilename(2);
  fs.writeFile('xmls/' + xjz + '.xml', xml, function(err, data) {

  });

  function getFilename(anyNumber) {
    let filename = 'xmlfilename' + anyNumber;
    return filename;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call your `getFilename()` function with a constant `2`. So each run through your `for (t = 0; t < 10; t++) { ... }` loop overwrites the same file.

Try using `let xjz = getFilename(t);` to get a different filename each time.

Comment: Wow thank you very much, i have done it now and it works.